# "Could not find declaration of file for module 'jwt-decode'

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

I'm using visual studio 2017 template for my angular project and i'm trying to import the 'jwt-decode' module after i have added it to package.json. I'm receiving the error (title of my post) after doing the following:

```
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
```

I have checked that the package is properly pulled down by npm.

I have searched other posts and done what has been recommended there but with no luck so far. Any help?

thanks
B

Comment: did you use angular2 ??

Comment: @robert i'm using angular 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Angular2/4 -Jwt need to use like that

```
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';
jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();

useJwtHelper() {
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  console.log(
    this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token),
    this.jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(token),
    this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)
  );
}
```

If you want know more refer the docs [Angular2/4 Jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)